# Non-positively algebraic number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, roots, algebraic-numbers

Let us say that an algebraic number $\alpha \in \mathbf{R}$ is *non-positively algebraic* if it is the root of a monic polynomial $p(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + a_{n-2}x^{n-2} + \dots + a_1 x + a_0$ where all coefficients $a_{i} \in \mathbf{Q}$ satisfy $a_i \leq 0$. Is anything known about this class of algebraic numbers? In particular, is there some non-positive algebraic number $\alpha$ which is not non-positively algebraic? Of course, all negative rationals are non-positively algebraic.

Contrast this with *positively algebraic* numbers, which is when the condition on the $a_i$ is $a_i \geq 0$. This has been somewhat studied, see e.g. [here](https://downloads.hindawi.com/archive/2014/296828.pdf). There are some algebraic numbers which are not positively algebraic. For example, the golden ratio $\varphi$ is non-positively algebraic but not positively algebraic.

Comment: What about the roots of $x^2-x+1$ ? I am not sure whether we can multiply this with another polynomial to get a polynomial with non-positive coefficients (apart from the leading coefficient). How can we prove such an impossibility in general at all ?

Comment: Consider reversing the signs. Certainly by that transformation, all *positively* algebraic numbers are also *non-positively* algebraic. But that suggests there should be a set of numbers which are positively algebraic but *not* NP algebraic based on sign reversals. Have you checked $-\phi$ for instance?

Comment: @EricSnyder I don't understand the logic of reversing the signs, maybe I am missing something. Note that the sign on the leading term ($x^n$) should always be positive.

Comment: @Peter Yes, interesting polynomial to consider. One way to prove it might be to show that all such numbers are Pisot numbers (I don't know at all if this is the case, but some small examples seems to indicate something like this).

Comment: I’m not sure if this leads anywhere, but by Descartes’ rule of signs, polynomials like in the OP have exactly one positive root. So the conjugates of such an algebraic number are never positive real numbers, except for at most one of them.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is positively algebraic, ie $p(\alpha)=0$ with $p$ rational, $p(0) \neq 0$, and $p$ monic with non-negative coefficients, then some $p_1(x)=p(x)(1+x)^N$ has positive coefficients and $p_1(\alpha)=0$; then, some $p_2(x)=p_1(x)(x-D)$ (where $D$ is a large integer) is monic, all its other coefficients are non-negative rational numbers, and $p_2(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: @Aphelli Re: your first comment, good point! So in fact, any NPA is PA, by Descartes + the linked theorem. I think your second comment intends show that any PA number is NPA. But I don't quite follow. If all the coefficients of $p_2(x)$ are non-negative, then I don't see what we gained from the transform (after all this is true for $p(x)$ as well). If you mean that all coefficients of $p_2(x)$ are non-positive, then I don't see how this happens (if $D$ is massive then surely this can fail?). E.g. if $p(x) = x^2 + 3x + 1$ (with positive root), then what do you intend for $p_2(x)$ to be?

Comment: Oops, I meant “negative rational numbers” for the coefficients of $p_2$, sorry. Yes, that comment was supposed to show that PA implies NPA.

Comment: @Aphelli I confess I am a little confused now (my own fault). If NPA is indeed PA, then the golden ratio is PA -- but I thought it was not. Is there a known positive polynomial for it? The argument I envisioned (multiplying by $(x+1)^N$ for $N$ big enough) does not seem to work as far as I can tell... If things are clearer to you (I suspect they are!), then anything you could write in an answer would be very helpful!

Comment: Descartes sign-rule does not help at all here , what we have to determine is whether the minimal polynomial of the given number has a multiple of the desired form.

Comment: PA numbers have *no* positive real conjugates at all, so for instance the golden ratio or $\sqrt{2}$ aren’t PA (they’re NPA, though). @Peter: what do you mean? If a number is NPA, then its Galois conjugates are contained in the roots of the polynomial. By Descartes sign rule, it means that there’s at most one such positive conjugate. I don’t see why you say that’s of no help?

Comment: @Aphelli It is of no help because the question is not about the existence of specific roots. If we do not know whether there is a multiple of the desired form, we cannot conclude anything with the existence of such a root.

Comment: @Aphelli Ah, I was somehow overlooking the ridiculously easy fact that any positively algebraic number $\alpha$ must be non-positive, i.e. $\alpha \leq 0$... :)

Comment: @Peter: I’m more interested in the *uniqueness* of the positive root (as it constrains the conjugates of the algebraic number).

Comment: Further remark (the proof isn’t very hard): if $\alpha>0$ is NPA using the polynomial $p(x)$, then any root $\beta \neq \alpha$ of $p$ (in particular, conjugates of $\alpha$) satisfies $|\beta| \leq |\alpha|$. If equality holds, then we can write $p(x)=q(x^d)$, where $\beta^d =\alpha^d >0$.

Comment: @Aphelli In that case, do we also have that for all other conjugate roots $\beta \neq \alpha$ we have $|\beta| \leq 1$? I.e. is $\alpha$ a Pisot number?

Comment: That’s not possible, every positive rational multiple of a NPA is still NPA. I think what essentially remains is the case where $\alpha>0$ is algebraic, and for every conjugate $\beta\neq \alpha$, we have $|\beta| < |\alpha|$ (this should be the case for some power of any given NPA) – I wonder if that’s a sufficient condition for being NPA?